# How to select the last value/index based on last occurence with a certain regular expression in a list in Python?

Tags: python

I'm performing certain calculations on a large .txt(tab delimited, 300+ columns, 1 000 000+ rows) file using following code:

```
samples = []
OTUnumber = []

with open('all.16S.uniq.txt','r') as file:
     for i,line in enumerate(file): 
        columns = line.strip().split('\t')[11:353]
        if i == 0: #headers are sample names so first row
            samples = columns #save sample names 
            OTUnumbers = [0 for s in samples] #set starting value as zero
        else:
            for n,v in enumerate(columns):
                if v > 0:
                    OTUnumber[n] = OTUnumber[n] + 1
                else:
                    continue

result = dict(zip(samples,OTUnumbers))
```

I'm having a question about a certain part of this code.
**Code of interest:**

```
columns = line.strip().split('\t')[11:353] ###row i is splitted and saved as a list
```

The .txt file has a lot of columns and I'm only interested in part of the columns. I frequently generate these kind of .txt files and the columns of interest always start at index 11 but do not always end at index 353. The last columns are never columns of interest. I want to "automate" this code so that Python performs the code on the columns of interest.

The name of all columns of interest start with "sample". So basically I want to select the last column with the regular expression "sample". Mind that I read a line of the file, split it, and then save it as a list (= `columns`)
**Code I'm looking for**:

````
columns = line.strip().split('\t')[11:```LAST COLUMN WHICH STARTS WITH "sample"```]
````

Based upon some research on the web I tried following code, but it returns a SyntaxError.

```
columns = line.strip().split('\t') 11:columns.where(columns==^[sample]).last_valid_index()]
```

Any ideas how to write this code?

**UPDATE:**

```
OTUnumber = []

import re

with open('all.16S.uniq.txt','r') as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()
    for g in re.findall(r'^(?:[^\t]+\t){11}(.*(?:sample[^\t]+)).*$', data, flags=re.M):
        x=g.split('\t') #list containing all sample names

with open('all.16S.uniq.txt','r') as file:
     for i,line in enumerate(file): 
        columns = line.strip().split('\t')[x]
        if i == 0:
            samples = columns2 
            OTUnumber = [0 for s in samples] #
        else:
            for n,v in enumerate(columns):
                if int(v) > 0:
                    OTUnumber[n] = OTUnumber[n] + 1
                else:
                    continue

result = dict(zip(samples,OTUnumber))
```

returns error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with simple regex (with flags set to `re.MULTILINE`):

```
import re

data = '''
header 1\theader 2\theader 3\theader 4\theader 5\theader 6\theader 7\theader 8\theader 10\theader 11\theader 12\theader 13\theader 14
c1\tc2\tc3\tc4\tc5\tc6\tc7\tc8\tc9\tc 10\tc 11\tsample11\tsample12\tsample13\tc3\tc4
c1\tc2\tc3\tc4\tc5\tc6\tc7\tc8\tc9\tc 10\tc 11\tsample21\tsample22\tsample23\tsample24\tc4
c1\tc2\tc3\tc4\tc5\tc6\tc7\tc8\tc9\tc 10\tc 11\tsample31\tsample32\tc3
'''

for g in re.findall(r'^(?:[^\t]+\t){11}(.*(?:sample[^\t]+)).*$', data, flags=re.M):
    print(g.split('\t'))
```

Prints:

```
['sample11', 'sample12', 'sample13']
['sample21', 'sample22', 'sample23', 'sample24']
['sample31', 'sample32']
```

Edit (to read from file):

```
import re

with open('all.16S.uniq.txt','r') as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()
    for g in re.findall(r'^(?:[^\t]+\t){11}(.*(?:sample[^\t]+)).*$', data, flags=re.M):
        print(g.split('\t'))
```

Edit2: to get index of last column that contains sample:

```
import re

data = '''
header 1\theader 2\theader 3\theader 4\theader 5\theader 6\theader 7\theader 8\theader 10\theader 11\theader 12\theader 13\theader 14
c1\tc2\tc3\tc4\tc5\tc6\tc7\tc8\tc9\tc 10\tc 11\tsample11\tsample12\tsample13\tc3\tc4
c1\tc2\tc3\tc4\tc5\tc6\tc7\tc8\tc9\tc 10\tc 11\tsample21\tsample22\tsample23\tsample24\tc4
c1\tc2\tc3\tc4\tc5\tc6\tc7\tc8\tc9\tc 10\tc 11\tsample31\tsample32\tc3
'''

for g in re.findall(r'^(?:[^\t]+\t){11}(.*(?:sample[^\t]+)).*$', data, flags=re.M):
    print('Index of last column is:', 11 + len(g.split('\t')))
```

Prints:

```
Index of last column is: 14
Index of last column is: 15
Index of last column is: 13
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not quite sure how to implement your answer in my code. Could you clarify this?

Comment: @Robvh read your file to variable `data` and run this `re.findall()` on it.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with the code fully implemented in my original code? I can't figure it out.

Comment: It is still not 100% clear to me. With your code I can create a list which contain all the sample names, so that is good, but I don't know how to further use it. Can you check my updated question? I implemented your code.

Comment: @Robvh I don't understand what is the question. Load your data into list (e.g. through list comprehension) and use it in your program (I don't know what for you are using the data).

Comment: In my posted question you can see to complete code I'm using. I want to implement your code in my COMPLETE code. Can you perhaps check my original post again? With the line ```columns = line.strip().split('\t')[11:353]``` I select the columns 11 till 353, these are the columns which start with ''sample'' and 353 is the last column which starts with ''sample''. For my analysis, I only want the columns which start with "sample". However for another document, column 340 could be the last column which starts with "sample". In each file I want to know index  of the last col starting with "sample"

Comment: @Robvh Index of last column that starts with `sample` is `11 + len(g.split('\t'))` in code. Updated my answer.

Comment: With a bit of puzzeling the code you provided works! Thank you. I made an edit (under peer review) in your answer to make it clear, how I used it in my example.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using a custom function

**Ex:**

```
def get_last_sample_index(columns):
    for ind, c in enumerate(reversed(columns), 1):  #Reverse columns
        if c.startswith("sample"):                  #Get last column with `sample`
            return ind
    return -1

with open('all.16S.uniq.txt','r') as file:
    for i,line in enumerate(file):
        columns = line.strip().split('\t')
        columns = columns[11:-get_last_sample_index(columns)+1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code you provide does not seem to work. I think because you overwrite the columns variable again with ```columns = columns[11:-get_last_sample_index(columns)+1]```. Python returns a dictionary with all the samples, so that is correct, but all the samples have a value of 0.